# Driver for Lexmark X7675 printer 

Tags: 11.10, lexmark

#### Translation:

I would like to install a Lexmark X7675 printer. The installed Ubuntu version is 11.10.
I tried to look on the Lexmark website, but I only found drivers for Ubuntu versions older than 11.10.
So I tried to install the driver for 10.04 but without success. It ask for password on the terminal, I enter the correct password, but it ask for the password again. It is the administrator password.

#### Original (italian):

Vorrei installare la stampante Lexmark X7675.
La versione di ubuntu installata è la 11.10.
Ho provato a cercare nel sito Lexmark ma ho trovato versioni precendenti alla 11.10 .
Ho provato comunque ha installare la 10.04 ma niente da fare.
Installando i driver da terminale, chiede la password e, anche se corretta, non mi fa proseguire, richiedendomi nuovamente la password.
La password è quella di amministratore.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have this particular printer - but I can confirm your issue *if* you follow the [lexmark website](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&page=product&productCode=LEXMARK_X7675&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_UK&frompage=null) instructions... (N.B. download the *DEB* not the *RPM* package)

if you prefix *sudo* to the install instructions then the package is installed...

[image]

Obviously - since I dont have this printer, I cant get past this screen.  I hope you can :)