# Lexmark X6675 Printer stopped working on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, drivers, printing, lexmark

I have a problem.  I've just upgraded to 11.10 and my printer stopped working with error_log reporting:

```
The Printer cannot communicate with the computer.
```

From the research I have done people say on Windows the improper driver would cause this.  The driver that's available from Lexmark which I have had for both Lucid and Maverick apparently isn't supported on Oneiric.  What is interesting that System is recognizing the printer being present and the model as well as any devices being plugged into the card reader.

Has anyone gotten a Lexmark driver to work?

P.S. This question might be closely related but is asking for a different thing: [Driver for Lexmark X7675 printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70363/driver-for-lexmark-x7675-printer).

P.P.S I've just confirmed that it was working with Natty as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually haven't been able to resolve the question directly but I have been able to work around the problem.

The Printer X6675 has a wireless interface which allows connecting via network.  So I have deleted the printer that the driver had created with USB as an interface and used network printer configuration same as the laserjet to make it work with the PPD file that has been provided by the downloaded driver.

Here is the screenshot of the configuration.
[image]