# 12.10 Lexmark S605 insecure permissions error

Tags: 12.10, printing, lexmark

The S605 printer from lexmark is found and there is a provided option for the S600 Series when installing it. However, after the installation process it says it needs the program `/usr/lib/cups/filter//usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter`.

Now i know, that the downloadable packages from lexmark contain this file in a debian package, so i could use it from there, but: What does the structure above mean? `...//usr/local/...`

Are these two different locations? And has the file to be in both?

Thanks in advance, it's impressive how you guys actually know what you're doing (in contrary to mac or most windows users.)

Update: After installinge the packages from lexmark (which are for 12.04) it says at printer state: `idle .../printfilter has insecure permissions (0100775/uid=0/gid=0)`.

Can i modify the printfilter? Do i need to set up an administrative group? I read a guide somewhere, but didn't follow it for some reason i forgot.

Comment: This http://askubuntu.com/questions/101513/lexmark-s605-printer-not-working leads to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/70363/driver-for-lexmark-x7675-printer might be useful

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `/usr/lib/cups/filter//usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter` is intended as one directory - `/usr/lib/cups/filter/` typically has no subdirs.

But apparently you managed to install the desired package and now you're getting the new insecure permissions error. I'm assuming this message gives the directory as `/usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter` below.

What you need to do is change the ownership of `/usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter`:

```
$ sudo chown -R root /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter
```

Changing the group shouldn't be neccessary but if you want to be on the safe side, also do

```
    $ sudo chgrp -R root /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter
```

However, you *do* need to have root as the owner of `/usr/lib/cups/filter/`, if it isn't, do the same for that directory:

```
$ sudo chown -R root /usr/lib/cups/filter/
```

...and when you're done with changeing the permissions, do a reboot or:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Answer (score 1):

> /usr/lib/cups/filter//usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter

This should be 1 directory. The double // is evaluated as 1 / so it does nothing. It is probably to prevent inside the software that this dir is evaluated: /usr/lib/cups/filterusr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter. That would result in an unwanted error.

> Permissions error

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin
sudo chgrp root /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter
```

should do it (though the 2nd line might not be needed!). Probable reason for the error:

CUPS 1.5.0 has a new security policy for filters and backends not allowing group write permissions. See http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/whatsnew.html

```
Scheduler

4. Filter security; Filters and backends must now have group
 write permissions disabled.
```

The package you used to install is probably from before this CUPS update.

Answer (score 0):

Following this link, but change the group by " bin " (not by " root ")

http://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/13737

Allows me to print on a lexmark s815 on linux mint 14 (based on ubuntu 12.10 so on debian 7)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that Rinzwind's answer about Cups ("*CUPS 1.5.0 has a new security policy for filters and backends not allowing group write permissions.*") was the key for me (I wanted to add a comment below his answer but I am new, so I couldn't do this). I had also been stuck with that insecure filter message and I was about to give up.

In case this helps anyone, my set up is: Linux Lite 3.8 (the last 32-bit version available), running on a cheap Chinese Grefu laptop, and the printer is a Ricoh SP112su.

I used the printer package kindly shared on Github for the [Ricoh SP100 series](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100), followed the Install instructions, but I was then bumping again and again into that "insecure filter" message until I found Rinzwind's answer on this thread. Both the test page and one pdf file were now printed OK. Thank you so much for the community!!

Comment: Thanks for adding some specific implementation details to your "comment" to make it into an answer, that may help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me on Linux Mint 15,  Lexmark Platinium Pro905

- Download and install Lexmark drivers and utilities Launch the lexmark
- printer utility and follow the instructions to install your printer
- `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter` `sudo chgrp bin`
- `/usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter` In the printer properties ->
  system preferences, enable remote administration

enjoy

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't mean that it will work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

This might only work on newer versions of cups. To reset cups use "sudo service cups restart" without quotation marks.

Comment: That only restart the service, not the underlying issue.